# Why 1000000 and 1_000_000 both are same?

Tags: javascript

```
const a = 1000000;
const b = 1_000_000;
```

now if i checked

```
console.log(1000000 === 1_000_000);
```

and it's return **true**

Why 1000000 and 1_000_000 both are same in javascript?

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators

Comment: Why wouldn't they be the same?  Is it because you are expecting a string comparison?

Comment: What result do you expect from `console.log(2 === 1+1);`?

Comment: your question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835092/making-large-numbers-in-javascript-code-more-readable

Comment: @ThomasSablik more like `1.0 === 1`

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, your example is better but all of these are expressions returning numbers.

Comment: @ThomasSablik true, it's just that `1+1` will do an extra operation, while `1.0` and `1` are exactly the same value, just like `1000000` and `1_000_000`

Answer (score 1):

Because the underscores are optional and purely for legibility.

Be careful using them in native JavaScript though, since they're not supported in all browsers: [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=numeric%20separators)